# In what set does this purplish star-stickered part belong?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Hello I need to identify this piece. In which set is it related too.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it's a [medium lavender 2x4 tile](https://brickset.com/parts/4651902/flat-tile-2x4) from [41055 - Cinderella's Romantic Castle](https://brickset.com/sets/41055-1/Cinderella-s-Romantic-Castle), based on this sticker sheet found on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/parts/10016414/sticker-sheet-1-for-set-41055-1/):

[image]

It is used to represent a bed/sofa there:

[image]